# Sending client data to another computer

Tags: javascript, sockets, gwt, web-applications

I'm a newbie in web programming. 
I'm now kind of stuck and lost.
Lets say that I have a content server (video). A client request a video from the server and a html page display the video on the client's web browser. At the same time, some data from the client have to be send to ANOTHER computer, which act as network monitor - lets say it has a database where the data will be stored into.

My questions are:

1.Let say that i'm using javascript to grab the data (i.e IP address), how do I send that data to the network monitor ? Or if it is not possible, is there any other method?

2.How do I build the network monitor?

I really need some hints and tips to kick start and to make sure that I learn the correct things. Any useful links will also be appreciated.

Thanks! =D

Answer (score 0):

You can send data to any server you want using a `form` and submit it to the url you set with `action`.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action="http://the-other-server.com" method="post" target="theIframe">
        <input type="hidden" name="data" value="{your:'data_here'}" />
    </form>
    <iframe name="theIframe" style="display:none"></iframe>
    <script>
        document.getElementsByTagName('FORM')[0].submit();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents you to read the information from another server(with a different protocol, sub-domain, domain or port). For instance get the response of your `POST` above.

To read the content of another domain you need to use a technique called [JSONP](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/)

**EDIT:** Or if you target modern browsers (> IE8), you can use `parent.postMessage` from an `iframe` of another origin to exchange string data with the main page.

And finally if you have to support older browsers, you can still use the [window.name Transport hack](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/22/windowname-transport/) passing data through the `window.name` property of an `iframe`

Comment: What about window.postmessage?

Comment: @Binbo I've edited the answer... how the heck I forgot that one!

Comment: thanks mic! you have actually gave me the base idea. Already solved it. I put the data received from the parent window into a hidden form inside the iframe and submitted it. The servlet then request the parameter and I can make MySQL query =D